# Ruby on Rails not saving data on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have CRUD that when creating a new entry, nothing is saved and no error is generated. I can see the post happening in the logs.

Controller

```
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :content end
```

Routes

```
map.resources :articles
```

Log

```
Parameters: {"article"=>{"title"=>"Dive trip", "content"=>"hfigoo"}, "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried this in `rails console`?

Comment: nope, not sure how to go about that?

Comment: gilbert, which version of rails are u using, 2 or 3? and on which os?  On my Linux (Ubuntu) for rails v2.x I do 'script/console' for rails 3.x I do 'script/rails console'  These are done at the application route.  They you are in an environment that is your application.  So you can issue 'line-by-line' commands like Model.new and Model.save and see errors.

Comment: it's rails 2. the issue i have is the site is on heroku and i have to do any debugging there

Comment: ok, type `heroku console`, then `a = Article.new({"article"=>{"title"=>"Dive trip", "content"=>"hfigoo"}, "commit"=>"Save changes"})` then `a.save`, and see what appears.

Answer (score 3):

One problem might be that it's failing its validations. But yes, as per the code I can't see any. You can do something like this

First check if the request comes to the create method, putting a simple puts command will do this.

If the request comes to the method use @article.save! instead of @article.save, this will tell you if there are any validation errors

Answer (score 1):

```
$ script/console
> a = Article.new({"title"=>"Dive trip", "content"=>"hfigoo"})
  => #<Article:.....
> a.save
```

When you see the response from `a.save` as either `=> false` or `=> true`. If SQL is executed, you should be able to see it in the console.

If you must run it on heroku, you can do

```
$ heroku console
```

to get the rails console on the heroku platform.

Comment: but when i try to save like the params above, i get this.

a = Article.new("article"=>{"title"=>"Dive trip", "content"=>"hfigoo"})
=> #<Article id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, sortorder: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: Remember, you are doing `Article.new(params[:article])` in code, so you pull out the sub hash for article, e.g. `Article.new({"title"=>"Dive trip", "content"=>"hfigoo"})`.

Comment: ok, thanks i didn't know that. Still not working from the app. Code is as my orig question and i still see the post however, no data. I can see the data entered from the console on my index page but new, the data just vanishes.